# Can you create a polyhedron (and fill it) in Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I would like to create a polyhedron (3D polygon) in Google Earth/KML. (For example, a cube defined by 8 points.) Is there a specific way to create a polyhedron? Or you just have to create multiple polygons (6 squares for a cube)?

If so, is there also a way to "fill" the polyhedron with a color?